# What is a "fundamental thermodynamic relation"?

Tags: thermodynamics, terminology

My professor handed me a quiz in which he said something like (I don't remember exactly) "write down the four fundamental thermodynamic relations for $A,G,H,U$".

I showed the differential elements of each of these state functions but I'm bothered by the term ["fundamental thermodynamic relation"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_thermodynamic_relation).

Peter Atkins' book on physical chemistry and many other sources (wikipedia included) seem to say that the only fundamental thermodynamic equation is

$$dU=TdS-pdV.$$

Wikipedia says something I think is ambiguous: "This is only one expression of the fundamental thermodynamic relation. It may be expressed in other ways, using different variables (e.g. using thermodynamic potentials)."

You might say that this isn't ambiguous at all. I sadly think it is. It's not telling me at all what a fundamental thermodynamic relation is. The only thing I can understand from that is that possibly a fundamental thermodynamic relation is a relation of $V,S,T,P$.

So my question is: What is the fundamental thermodynamic relation? Is it only the relation for $dU$? Or what is it?

Answer (score 3):

According to page 291 of Brian Cowan's Topics in Statistical Mechanics, a relation of the form

$$ U=U(S,V,N) $$

is referred to as the "fundamental relation" for the system. That is, internal energy (or more generally, a thermodynamic potential) expressed as a function of entropy $S$, volume $V$, and particle number $N$. Note that a relation of this form may be rearranged to give something like $G=...$, and so on.

What you have given is a specific example of a fundamental relation (sometimes referred to as the Gibbs-Duhem relation).

Comment: Why isn't pressure mentioned here? Is it because it will have something to do with $N$ ? Thanks.

Comment: @David Because pressure can be defined in terms of the variables given,$-\partial U/\partial V$. Similarly, temperature is $\partial U/\partial S$ and chemical potential $\partial U/\partial N$.

Comment: But wouldn't this be different than what Peter Atkins is saying (that the fundamental relation of thermodynamics is $dU=TdS-PdV$ ?

Comment: @David That's *one* possible expression of the fundamental relation specifically for a *closed* system. In general, an equation that relates a thermodynamic potential to entropy, volume, and particle number is a fundamental relation.

Comment: Wouldn't you say your reference would say that the expression I wrote for $dU$ isn't a fundamnetal thermodynamic relation?